# Classic ASP: On Error Stop

Tags: asp-classic, error-handling

I have an ASP page that runs two SQL insert statements at the beginning before displaying the page.  In the event I get a primary key conflict (ie. the inserts have already ran that day), I just want to carry on.

My code is basically:

```
on error resume next
' insert statements
```

Once the statements have been executed, I would like to resume the default error behaviour, where the page dies with an error message.

Is there a command, like "on error stop", or "on error die", or "on error default", or something to reset the error handling to it's default behaviour?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want it to throw an error without going to any sort of custom error handler, use:

```
On Error GoTo 0
```

You can test it out in a quick sample ASP page with the following:

```
<% Language="VBScript" %>

<% Response.Write "Hello" %>

<% On Error Resume Next
   Dim rs
   SET rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")
   
   'On Error Goto 0
   rs.MoveNext

%>

<% Response.Write "Bye" %>
```

With `On Error Goto 0` commented out, `Bye` will get written as normal.  With `On Error Goto 0` enabled, you'll get the following error:

> ADODB.Recordset error '800a0e78'
>
> Operation is not allowed when the object is closed.

Comment: Tried it out.  That's exactly what I'm looking for.  Thank you!